# Is there a way to wait until the plot has been completely refreshed in oxyplot?

Tags: c#, plot, graphics, oxyplot

Plots in oxyplot are update using the `PlotModel.InvalidatePlot(bool UpdateData)` method, however is there a way to wait for the refreshing process to complete before doing anything else in the code?

Answer (score 0):

I think this may solve your issue.

```
lock (MyModel.SyncRoot){
//Code in here will only run after model is refreshing process is complete
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).